# Logical Error while retriving data from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve data from `ArrayList` and sum 1st integer value.

I have tried multiple ways to do it but unable to get the expected result. I know there's some error in my logic. But I'm unable to get the expected results. Please help me figure it out.

```
int sum = 0;

List<String> sum_list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list21 = new ArrayList<>();
list21.add("1 tbsp olive oil plus a drizzle to serve (optional)");
list21.add("1 tbsp olive oil plus a drizzle to serve (optional)");
list21.add("2 tbsp pesto");
list21.add("2 tbsp pesto");
list21.add("2 tbsp pesto");
list21.add("2 tbsp pesto");
int i = 0;
while (i < list21.size()) {

    String str1 = list21.get(i).trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
    String str2 = list21.get(i + 1).trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

    if (str1.equals(str2)) {

        sum += Integer.valueOf(list21.get(i).replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"))
                + Integer.valueOf(list21.get(i).replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
        // System.out.println("Sum=" + sum);
        try {
            if (!sum_list.isEmpty() && !sum_list.get(sum_list.size() - 1).trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "").contains(str2)) {
                sum_list.add(sum + " " + str1);
                sum = 0;
            } else sum_list.add(sum + " " + str1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    i = i + 2;
}
System.out.println(sum_list.toString());
```

**Expected Result**

> 2  tbsp olive oil plus a drizzle to serve (optional), 10  tbsp pesto

**Output of code**

> 2  tbsp olive oil plus a drizzle to serve (optional), 6  tbsp pesto,4  tbsp pesto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have understood your logic and made some changes to the code. Here is the block of code which you can replace, the while loop.

```
for(String ops : list21){

    if(sum_list.size()==0){
        sum_list.add(ops);
    }
    else{
         String str= ops.trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
         String str_from_list=sum_list.get(sum_list.size()-1).replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();

         if(str_from_list.contains(str.trim())){
            System.out.println("found");
            int val= Integer.valueOf(sum_list.get(sum_list.size()-1).replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
            int to_add = Integer.valueOf(ops.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
            int total = val+to_add;
            sum_list.set(sum_list.size()-1,total+" "+str_from_list);
         }
         else{
            sum_list.add(ops);  
         }
    }
System.out.println(sum_list);


}
```

Things to note

1. Remove the print statements where ever required.
2. This is done with the assumption in mind that only sequential operations has to be aggregated.

[EDIT]

To check if it exists without the sequence of order in the list, please use the code block below.

```
for(String ops : list21){

    if(sum_list.size()==0){
        sum_list.add(ops);
    }
    else{
        String str= ops.trim().replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
        int index=-1;
        String str_from_list=null;
        for(String str_from_l : sum_list){
            str_from_list=str_from_l.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();

            if(str_from_list.contains(str.trim())){
                index=sum_list.indexOf(str_from_l);
                break;
            }
        }


         if(index!=-1){
           // System.out.println("found");
            int val= Integer.valueOf(sum_list.get(index).replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
            int to_add = Integer.valueOf(ops.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"));
            int total = val+to_add;

            sum_list.set(index,total+" "+str_from_list);
         }
         else{
            sum_list.add(ops);  
         }
    }



}
System.out.println(sum_list);
```

Comment: you are free to optimize by using less variables, and change the variable names according to the standards.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can this be used in a general term order? I mean in any sorted `ArrayList` as I've to use this in mine project?

Comment: Yes. If you have a sorted ArrayList, it will be working fine. 
Problem would occur in cases where if the order is 
1 tbsp A, 1 tbsp B, 1 tbsp A, then the result will be same, not 2 tbsp A, 1 tbsp B. Let me know if you want the logic to be reframed that way. If you find this answer useful please mark it as accepted by click on the tick mark on the left of this answer. Feel free to upvote if you agree with the answer.

Comment: I'm having data like **2tbsp, 1tbsp** in this form. where am I supposed to make a change to support that as well?

Comment: yes. 
for the case 1 tbsp A, 1 tbsp B, 1 tbsp A what should be your answer ? [2 tbsp A, 1 tbsp B] or [t tbsp A, 1 tbsp B, 1 tbsp B]

Comment: it should add them as well. **1tbsp,3tbsp,2tbsp** it should give **6tbsp**

Comment: what if the order is changed? It fails that time.

Comment: yes. you need to add a loop to check that as well. add a loop for sum list and check if it exists in sum list.

Comment: added that in the edit, you can use the second block of the code snippets.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. it has solved the problem.